# How do I programmatically set the docstring?

Tags: python-2.7, docstring

I have a wrapper function that returns a function. Is there a way to programmatically set the docstring of the returned function? If I could write to `__doc__` I'd do the following:

```
def wrapper(a):
    def add_something(b):
       return a + b
    add_something.__doc__ = 'Adds ' + str(a) + ' to `b`'
    return add_something
```

Then I could do

```
>>> add_three = wrapper(3)
>>> add_three.__doc__
'Adds 3 to `b`
```

However, since `__doc__` is read-only, I can't do that. What's the correct way?

---

Edit: Ok, I wanted to keep this simple, but of course this is not what I'm actually trying to do. Even though in general `__doc__` is writeable in my case it isn't.

I am trying to create testcases for `unittest` automatically. I have a wrapper function that creates a class object that is a subclass of `unittest.TestCase`:

```
import unittest
def makeTestCase(filename, my_func):
    class ATest(unittest.TestCase):
        def testSomething(self):
            # Running test in here with data in filename and function my_func
            data  = loadmat(filename)
            result = my_func(data)
            self.assertTrue(result > 0)

    return ATest
```

If I create this class and try to set the docstring of `testSomething` I get an error:

```
>>> def my_func(): pass
>>> MyTest = makeTestCase('some_filename', my_func)
>>> MyTest.testSomething.__doc__ = 'This should be my docstring'
AttributeError: attribute '__doc__' of 'instancemethod' objects is not writable
```

Comment: Why don't you just write a docstring?

Comment: @RaeKettler: Because then if you update it, you have to always remember to manually update all the other copies in all the other wrapper functions

Comment: **The reported issue is specific to Python 2.x**. In 3.x, there is not a separate `instancemethod` type, and code like what is shown works as is (although the `__doc__` could not be set for something that actually is a method *of an instance*, like `MyTest().testSomething.__doc__ = '...'`). Also, the example above the line **does work, even in 2.x**. (I keep it installed specifically to investigate old questions like this.)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I would pass the docstring into the factory function and use `type` to manually construct the class.

```
def make_testcase(filename, myfunc, docstring):
    def test_something(self):
        data = loadmat(filename)
        result = myfunc(data)
        self.assertTrue(result > 0)

    clsdict = {'test_something': test_something,
               '__doc__': docstring}
    return type('ATest', (unittest.TestCase,), clsdict)

MyTest = makeTestCase('some_filename', my_func, 'This is a docstring')
```

Answer (score 62):

An `instancemethod` gets its docstring from its `__func__`.  Change the docstring of `__func__` instead. (The `__doc__` attribute of functions are writeable.)

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def bar(self):
...         pass
...
>>> Foo.bar.__func__.__doc__ = "A super docstring"
>>> help(Foo.bar)
Help on method bar in module __main__:

bar(self) unbound __main__.Foo method
    A super docstring

>>> foo = Foo()
>>> help(foo.bar)
Help on method bar in module __main__:

bar(self) method of __main__.Foo instance
    A super docstring
```

From the [2.7 docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html):

> User-defined methods
>
> A user-defined method object combines a class, a class instance (or None) and any callable
> object (normally a user-defined function).
>
> Special read-only attributes: im_self is the class instance object, im_func is the function
> object; im_class is the class of im_self for bound methods or the class that asked for the
> method for unbound methods; **`__doc__` is the method’s documentation (same as
> `im_func.__doc__`);** `__name__` is the method name (same as `im_func.__name__`);
> `__module__` is the name of the module the method was defined in, or None if unavailable.
>
> Changed in version 2.2: im_self used to refer to the class that defined the method.
>
> Changed in version 2.6: For 3.0 forward-compatibility, **im_func is also available as
> `__func__`,** and im_self as `__self__`.

Answer (score 12):

Just use decorators. Here's your case:

```
def add_doc(value):
    def _doc(func):
        func.__doc__ = value
        return func
    return _doc

import unittest
def makeTestCase(filename, my_func):
    class ATest(unittest.TestCase):
        @add_doc('This should be my docstring')
        def testSomething(self):
            # Running test in here with data in filename and function my_func
            data  = loadmat(filename)
            result = my_func(data)
            self.assertTrue(result > 0)

    return ATest

def my_func(): pass

MyTest = makeTestCase('some_filename', my_func)
print MyTest.testSomething.__doc__
> 'This should be my docstring'
```

Here's a similar use case: [Python dynamic help and autocomplete generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603088/python-dynamic-help-and-autocomplete-generation)

Answer (score 10):

This is an addition to the fact that the `__doc__` attribute of classes of type `type` cannot be changed. The interesting point is that this is only true as long as the class is created using type. As soon as you use a metaclass you can actually just change `__doc__`.

The example uses the abc (AbstractBaseClass) module. It works using a special `ABCMeta` metaclass

```
import abc

class MyNewClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

MyClass.__doc__ = "Changing the docstring works !"

help(MyNewClass)
```

will result in

```
"""
Help on class MyNewClass in module __main__:

class MyNewClass(__builtin__.object)
 |  Changing the docstring works !
"""
```

Comment: This is not related to the question that was asked. The example is not trying to set a `__doc__` attribute on a class, but on a method.

Answer (score 4):

`__doc__` is not writable only when your object is of type 'type'.

In your case, `add_three` is a function and you can just set `__doc__` to any string.

Answer (score 0):

In the case where you're trying to automatically generate unittest.TestCase subclasses, you may have more mileage overriding their [shortDescription](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.shortDescription) method.

This is the method that strips the underlying docstring down to the first line, as seen in normal unittest output; overriding it was enough to give us control over what showed up in reporting tools like TeamCity, which was what we needed.