# Fabric docstring for classy tasks

Tags: python, fabric

I have defined a number of fabric tasks by subclassing Task (as described here: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/tasks.html#task-subclasses). I'd like to have a docstring in order to describe what each task subclass does which will be displayed on `fab -l` just like when definining tasks with the `@task` decorator. I tried putting the docstring in a number of places (after `class`, after `def run`) but it didn't work.

Is it possible to have a `fab -l` visible description for tasks defined as subclasses of `Task`  ?

For instance, here's a portion of my fabfile:

```
class BaseConfig(Task):
    def run(self):
        env.env = self.name
        env.user = 'serafeim'
        env.role = self.name
        puts("Using {0} configuration with user {1} at {2}".format(env.env, env.user, env.roledefs[env.env]))

class UatConfig(BaseConfig):
    """
    UAT settings
    """
    name = "uat"
uat_cfg_instance = UatConfig()


class ProdConfig(BaseConfig):
    """
    Prod settings
    """
    name = "prod"
prod_cfg_instance = ProdConfig()
```

When I run fab -l I only see

```
uat
dev
```

without any description of what these do.

Comment: Could you share a piece of code with your interesting question? You are also refering to some Task description, but you probably forgot to put the link into your question.

Comment: Oops ! Yes, I forgot the link -- I added it now though along with a part of my fabfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Fabric==1.8.3`:

Your code with added imports and managing docstring for tasks:  **fabfile.py**:

```
from fabric.api import *
from fabric.tasks import Task

class BaseConfig(Task):
    """BaseConfig task docstring"""
    def run(self):
        """BaseConfig task docstring for `run` method"""
        env.env = self.name
        env.user = 'serafeim'
        env.role = self.name
        puts("Using {0} configuration with user {1} at {2}".format(env.env, env.user, env.roledefs[env.env]))

class UatConfig(BaseConfig):
    """
    UAT settings
    """
    name = "uat"
uat_cfg_instance = UatConfig()


class ProdConfig(BaseConfig):
    """
    Prod settings

    talking a bit more about our classy concept, not yet diving into `run` details
    """
    name = "prod"
    def run(self):
        """ProdConfig run docstring

        on multiple lines
        we are now in prod"""
        super(ProdConfig, self).run()

prod_cfg_instance = ProdConfig()
```

## Listing available tasks

```
$ fab -l
Available commands:

    prod  Prod settings
    uat   UAT settings
```

Here we see, that docstring from class derived from Task is used - but just the first line.

## Show detailed docstring for uat - docstring from super class

Detailed description for `uat` illustrates the problem you have described:

```
$ fab -d uat
Displaying detailed information for task 'uat':

    BaseConfig task docstring for `run` method
    Arguments: self
```

As `uat` does not redefine `run` method, parent `run` method is used and this applies to presenting docstring for task details.

## Show detailed docstring for prod - docstring from `run` method

For `prod` we redefine `run` method and this gives us us a chance to modify docstring for the task:

```
$ fab -d prod
Displaying detailed information for task 'prod':

    ProdConfig run docstring

            on multiple lines
            we are now in prod
    Arguments: self
```

## Conclusions

- brief listing (via `$ fab -l`) shows first line of class docstring
- detailed listing (via `$ fab -d <taskname>`) shows docstring from used `run` method
- if you want to change task detailed docstring, you have to define `run` method in your inherited class and specify the docstring there. Do not forget to call `run` from super class (if it is relevant).

Answer (score 1):

In order to display the docstring of the subclass when `fab -d` is called, the following works for me in Fabric 1.13.1:

```
 class BaseConfig(Task):
        def run(self):
            env.env = self.name
            env.user = 'serafeim'
            env.role = self.name
            puts("Using {0} configuration with user {1} at {2}".format(env.env, env.user, env.roledefs[env.env]))

        def __details__(self):
            return self.__doc__
```

And voila:

```
$ fab -d provision.prod
Displaying detailed information for task 'provision.prod':

    Prod settings

$ fab -d provision.uat
Displaying detailed information for task 'provision.uat':

    UAT settings
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same docstring for the Task class and `run()` method, use the following way:

```
from fabric.api import *
from fabric.tasks import Task


class BaseConfig(Task):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseConfig, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Update docstring of run() so `fab -d <task>` will show the same
        # docstring of the class
        if self.__doc__:
            # http://stackoverflow.com/a/4835557/2293304
            self.run.__func__.__doc__ = self.__doc__


class FooConfig(BaseConfig):
    """
    Foo docstring

    This is the foo description.
    """
    name = 'foo'

    def run(self):
        # This method will automatically use the docstring of the class
        puts('This run foo...')


foo_instance = FooConfig()
```