# how to create a new method with signature of another

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, proxy

How can I copy the signature of a method from one class, and create a "proxy method" with same signature in another ?.

I am writing a RPC library in python.
The server supports remote calls to a server-side class (C).
When the client connects to the server, it should create a proxy class for C with same  signatures.
When the program calls proxy instance, it should call the function with same arguments at the server.

Answer (score 4):

Consider using [boltons.wraps](https://boltons.readthedocs.io/en/latest/funcutils.html#boltons.funcutils.wraps) - here's an excerpt from the documentation:

> boltons.funcutils.wraps(func, injected=None, **kw)
>
> Modeled after the built-in functools.wraps(), this function is used to
>   make your decorator’s wrapper functions reflect the wrapped
>   function’s:
>
> Name Documentation Module Signature
>
> The built-in functools.wraps() copies the first three, but does not
>   copy the signature. This version of wraps can copy the inner
>   function’s signature exactly, allowing seamless usage and
>   introspection. Usage is identical to the built-in version:
>
> ```
> >>> from boltons.funcutils import wraps
> >>>
> >>> def print_return(func):
> ...     @wraps(func)
> ...     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
> ...         ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
> ...         print(ret)
> ...         return ret
> ...     return wrapper
> ...
> >>> @print_return
> ... def example():
> ...     '''docstring'''
> ...     return 'example return value'
> >>>
> >>> val = example()
> example return value
> >>> example.__name__
> 'example'
> >>> example.__doc__
> 'docstring'
> ```
>
> In addition, the boltons version of wraps supports modifying the outer
>   signature based on the inner signature. By passing a list of injected
>   argument names, those arguments will be removed from the outer
>   wrapper’s signature, allowing your decorator to provide arguments that
>   aren’t passed in.
>
> Parameters:    func (function) – The callable whose attributes are to
>   be copied.
>
> injected (list) – An optional list of argument names which should not
>   appear in the new wrapper’s signature.
>
> update_dict (bool) – Whether to copy other, non-standard attributes of
>   func over to the wrapper. Defaults to True.
>
> inject_to_varkw (bool) – Ignore missing arguments when a **kwargs-type
>   catch-all is present. Defaults to True.
>
> For more in-depth wrapping of functions, see the FunctionBuilder type,
>   on which wraps was built.

Answer (score 2):

You don't *have* to copy the function signature. Instead, accept arbitrary positional and keyword arguments and pass those on:

```
def proxy_function(*args, **kw):
    return original_function(*args, **kw)
```

Here the `*args` and `**kw` syntax in the `proxy_function` signature are given a tuple and dictionary, respectively, of arguments passed into the function:

```
>>> def foo(*args, **kw):
...     print args
...     print kw
... 
>>> foo('spam', 'ham', monty='python')
('spam', 'ham')
{'monty': 'python'}
```

Similarly, the `*args` and `**kw` syntax in the `original_function()` call takes a sequence or a mapping, respectively, to apply their contents as separate arguments to the function being called:

```
>>> def bar(baz, fourtytwo=42):
...     print baz
...     print fourtytwo
... 
>>> args = ('hello world!',)
>>> kwargs = {'fourtytwo': 'the answer'}
>>> bar(*args, **kwargs)
hello world!
the answer
```

Combined, the two serve as an arbitrary-argument-pass-through for proxy functions.

Creating a full facade on the other hand is a little more involved:

```
import inspect

_default = object()

def build_facade(func):
    """Build a facade function, matching the signature of `func`.

    Note that defaults are replaced by _default, and _proxy will reconstruct
    these to preserve mutable defaults.

    """
    name = func.__name__
    docstring = func.__doc__
    spec = inspect.getargspec(func)
    args, defaults = spec[0], spec[3]
    boundmethod = getattr(func, '__self__', None)

    arglen = len(args)
    if defaults is not None:
        defaults = zip(args[arglen - len(defaults):], defaults)
        arglen -= len(defaults)

    def _proxy(*args, **kw):
        if boundmethod:
            args = args[1:]  # assume we are bound too and don't pass on self
        # Reconstruct keyword arguments
        if defaults is not None:
            args, kwparams = args[:arglen], args[arglen:]
            for positional, (key, default) in zip(kwparams, defaults):
                if positional is _default:
                    kw[key] = default
                else:
                    kw[key] = positional
        return func(*args, **kw)

    args = inspect.formatargspec(formatvalue=lambda v: '=_default', *spec)
    callargs = inspect.formatargspec(formatvalue=lambda v: '', *spec)

    facade = 'def {}{}:\n    """{}"""\n    return _proxy{}'.format(
        name, args, docstring, callargs)
    facade_globs = {'_proxy': _proxy, '_default': _default}
    exec facade in facade_globs
    return facade_globs[name]
```

This produces a whole new function object with the same argument names, and handles defaults by referencing the original proxied function defaults rather than copy them to the facade; this ensures that even mutable defaults continue to work.

The facade builder handles *bound* methods too; in that case `self` is removed from the call before passing on, to ensure that the target method is not getting an extra `self` argument (which would be the wrong type anyway).

Handling *unbound* methods is out of scope here; provide your own `_proxy` function in that case that can instantiate the proxied class and pass on arguments without the `self` or provide a new value for `self`; you cannot pass in `self` unaltered.

Demo:

```
>>> def foobar(bar, baz, default=[]):
...     print bar, baz, default
... 
>>> build_facade(foobar)
<function foobar at 0x10258df50>
>>> build_facade(foobar)('spam', 'eggs')
spam eggs []
>>> inspect.getargspec(build_facade(foobar))
ArgSpec(args=['bar', 'baz', 'default'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=(<object object at 0x102593cd0>,))
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def bar(self, spam): print spam
... 
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> class FooProxy(object):
...     bar = build_facade(foo.bar)
... 
>>> FooProxy().bar('hello!')
hello!
>>> inspect.getargspec(FooProxy.bar)
ArgSpec(args=['self', 'spam'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
```

Comment: thanks, but I want to copy the signature.
when I type "help(proxy.foo)", I see the full description of the function.

Comment: @dk7: **why** do you need to copy the signature? Are you introspecting the result? Why are you introspecting the result?

Comment: @dk7: The technique here is what is used by the vast majority of RPC libraries; examples: [stdlib `xmlrpclib` method object](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/fd5f7ce6b66a/Lib/xmlrpclib.py#l1215), [PySimpleSoap `call`](https://github.com/pysimplesoap/pysimplesoap/blob/master/pysimplesoap/client.py#L179), [python-jsonrpc client `call` function](https://github.com/gerold-penz/python-jsonrpc/blob/master/pyjsonrpc/http.py#L85).

Comment: I want the application to be more user friendly when running it with python console for debug mode.

Comment: late to the party, but for future reference: Martijin approach works, and I believe is the pythonic way to do it. To accomodate dk7 needs, docstrings could be added dynamically by setting proxy.__doc__ = orig_func.__doc__. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056983/how-do-i-programmatically-set-the-docstring for additional details.

Comment: I checked this stuff and it actually works and resolves http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40345337/change-list-of-functions-arguments as well.