# How to override original signature of a function in python

Tags: python

Let's say I have the following function:

```
def person(*args, **kwargs):
    '''
       person(name, age, parents=2)
       this is a docstring.
    '''
```

If I execute `help(person)` I would get

```
person(*args, **kwargs)
    person(name, age, children=5)
    this is a docstring.
```

But instead, I want to see:

```
person(name, age, children=5)
    this is a docstring.
```

Comment: Please provide more information. E.g., what is "the documentation"?

Comment: @JanStránský The docstring of the function..

Comment: are you looking for [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.partial)?

Comment: @MrFuppes can you use it to override the function signature? (or hide it)

Comment: So modifying existing docstring? something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056983/how-do-i-programmatically-set-the-docstring)?

Comment: Or simply adding a function docstring as proposed by Yeji Ha?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply overwrite `.__doc__` attribute:

```py
def a():
    """orig docstring"""
    pass
help(a)
a.__doc__ = """modified docstring"""
help(a)
```

Comment: I tried to edit my question to make it a bit more clear. My question is not how to set the docstring of the function but rather changing the signature (i.e. when calling `help(person)` I don't want to see `person(*args, **kwargs)` but rather `person(name, age, parents=2)` ONLY.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use docstrings, like this:

```
def function(...):
    """
    This function does this and that. The parameters are the following:
    param1 = ...
    param2 = ...
    ...
    """
    # code
```

Then you can simply call the .**doc** method and it prints out the docstring. It works like this:

```
    print.__doc__
```

Or for better readability:

```
    import pprint
    pprint.pprint(pprint.__doc__, indent=4)
```

Pprint is pretty print.

Comment: This is not what I asked. I asked how you can override the original signature of a function, for example, if you press `shift+tab` to see the doc of a function in jupyter notebook you will be presented with the function signature and doc string, what I want is to either override the function signature or hide it.

Comment: "This is not what I asked" - as you see from this answer and also the discussion below OP, it is not really clear what you have asked..

Comment: To be honest, your question was rather vague. To my knowledge, overriding (as in C++) is not possible in Python.

Comment: Excuse me if wasn't clear enough, I am trying to achieve something like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082570/override-function-declaration-in-autodoc-for-sphinx/12087750#12087750) answer but it doesn't seem to work for me, hence my question.