# Can a Python docstring be calculated (f-string or %-expression)?

Tags: python, docstring

Is it possible to have a Python docstring calculated? I have a lot of repetitive things in my docstrings, so I'd like to either use f-strings or a %-style format expression.

When I use an f-string at the place of a docstring

- importing the module invokes the processing
- but when I check the `__doc__` of such a function it is empty
- sphinx barfs when the docstring is an f-string

I do know how to process the docstrings after the import, but that doesn't work for object 'doc' strings which is recognized by sphinx but is not a real `__doc__`'s of the object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I programmatically set the docstring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056983/how-do-i-programmatically-set-the-docstring)

Comment: No, that is basically what I do now because an f-string as docstring doesn't seem to work, at least not with sphinx, and it is not recognized by checker tools. But it does seem to be 'executed' by normal Python.

Comment: Please show what the problem was with what you've tried.

Comment: I rolled that back

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Docstrings in Python must be regular string literals.

This is pretty easy to test - the following program does not show the docstring:

```
BAR = "Hello world!"

def foo():
        f"""This is {BAR}"""
        pass

assert foo.__doc__ is None
help(foo)
```

The Python syntax docs say that [the docstring must be a "string literal"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#id19), and the tail end of [the f-string reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) says they "cannot be used as docstrings".

So unfortunately you must use the `__doc__` attribute.

However, you should be able to use a decorator to read the `__doc__` attribute and replace it with whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I feared. Unfortunately, post-processing the \_\_doc__ strings doesn't work for objects, which are important for me ;(

Comment: I guess I'll have to preprocess the whole file before passing it to sphinx.

Comment: How would you make it work on sphinx? Indeed it is not working with Sphinx.

Answer (score 4):

We had the same problem, and what we might end up doing is this:

```
BAR = "Hello world!"

class A():
    __doc__ = f"""This is {BAR}"""
    pass

help(A)
```

Comment: Do you know if this works for napoleon sphinx?